# Get Email Addresses from Active Directory by passing Group Name in JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to create a function which return Email Addresses of All Group members from Active Directory by taking Group Name as an input Parameter, the result will be a ";" separate String.

I found following code but is returning only First member Email address not all members can you please guide me what is problem in below code or is there any other way in Java to get it done :
Thanks

```
public String fetchGroupMembers(String strGroupName)
    {
        Vector memberEmails = new Vector();
        String strEmails = "";    
        try
        { 
            //Create the initial directory context
            //DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(ctx);
            //Create the search controls        
            SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
            //Specify the search scope
            searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            //specify the LDAP search filter
            String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(CN="+strGroupName+"))";
            //Specify the Base for the search
            //String searchBase =searchBase;
            //initialize counter to total the group members
            int totalResults = 0;

            //Specify the attributes to return
            String returnedAtts[]={"member", "mail"};
            searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

            //Search for objects using the filter
            NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
            //Loop through the search results
            while (answer.hasMoreElements())
            {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
                //System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                if (attrs != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll();ae.hasMore();)
                        {
                            Attribute attr = (Attribute)ae.next();
                            //System.out.println("Attribute: " + attr.getID());
                            for (NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll();e.hasMore();totalResults++)
                            {
                                String str = e.next().toString();
                                //System.out.println(" " +  totalResults + ". " + str );
                                int end = str.indexOf(",");
                                //System.out.println("end " + end);
                                if(end != -1)
                                {
                                    String str1 = str.substring(3, end);
                                    //System.out.println("Name-->>" + str1 + "<<");
                                    doFilterSearch(str1.trim(), memberEmails);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }    
                    catch (NamingException e)
                    {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                        System.err.println("Problem listing members: " + e);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Total members: " + totalResults);
            ctx.close();
        }
```

And Filter Code :

```
public void doFilterSearch(String employeeID,Vector memberEmails) throws Exception{

    SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
    ctls. setReturningObjFlag (true);
    ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String[] attrIDs = {"sn","mail"};
    ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
    //System.out.println("Searching For :: " + employeeID);
    String filter = "(&(objectclass=*)(cn="+employeeID+"))"; //  ( mail=*)  // , "mail","manager"

    NamingEnumeration myInum = ctx.search(searchBase, filter, ctls);
    //formatResults(answer , grievanceBean);
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
        while (myInum.hasMoreElements())
        {
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)myInum.next();
            //grievanceBean = formatAttributes(sr.getAttributes() , grievanceBean);
            for (NamingEnumeration enuNaming = sr.getAttributes().getAll(); enuNaming.hasMore();) 
            {
                 Attribute attrib = (Attribute)enuNaming.nextElement();
                 String attrName = attrib.getID();
                // System.out.println("ATTRIBUTE Name : " + attrib.getID());
                // System.out.println("ATTRIBUTE Value: " + attrib.toString());

                 if (attrName.equalsIgnoreCase("mail"))
                 {  
                        String attrValue = attrib.toString();
                        int length = attrValue.length();
                        String mail = attrValue.substring(attrValue.indexOf(":")+2,length);

                        //System.out.println("Mail :: -->" + mail + "<--");
                        //System.out.println("E-mail :: -->>" + (mail.substring(mail.indexOf(":") + 1, mail.length())).trim() + "<<--");
                        memberEmails.add((mail.substring(mail.indexOf(":") + 1, mail.length())).trim());
                   }
            }
            count++;
        }
       //System.out.println("Search returned " + count + " results");
    }
    catch (NamingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ctx.close();
}
```

EDIT :
Thanks for your guidance, I am getting Error when it getting second email address

```
================= Debug Result ===========================
>>>CN=GRP_WF_XXXXNF,OU=DMS
Attribute: member
 0. CN=MAk,OU=HR,DC=xxx,DC=com
Name-->>MAk<<
Searching For :: MAk
ATTRIBUTE Name : mail
ATTRIBUTE Value: mail: mak@xxx.coom
Mail :: -->mak@xxx.coom<--
E-mail :: -->>mak@xxx.coom<<--
ATTRIBUTE Name : sn
ATTRIBUTE Value: sn: SAk
Search returned 1 results
 1. CN=Msi,OU=HR,,DC=xxx,DC=com
end 33
Name-->>Msi<<
Searching For :: Msi
Total members: 1
mak@xxx.coom
exception :: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getURLOrDefaultInitDirCtx(InitialDirContext.java:106)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267)
    at com.mzec.model.ADModel.doFilterSearch(ADModel.java:388)
    at com.mzec.model.ADModel.fetchGroupMembers(ADModel.java:270)
    at com.mzec.model.ADModel.main(ADModel.java:439)
Problem listing members: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

Line 388

```
NamingEnumeration myInum = ctx.search(searchBase, filter, ctls);
```

Comment: Can someone explain why I got "-1" ??

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't explain what you've tried so far. Have you tried uncommenting all those `println`s and analyzed the output? Have you run it in a debugger to see what it does? Which aspect of the above code is unclear to you?

Comment: Thanks Hulk for your guidance, I am getting Error when it getting second email address Debug Result is in EDIT

Comment: I also checked with different Groups it always give error on second member, for First member I am getting Email address

Comment: Line 388 is    NamingEnumeration myInum = ctx.search(searchBase, filter, ctls); also updated in question edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to run your code, but if I counted your braces correctly, you are closing your `DirContext` with the loop:

```
System.out.println("Total members: " + totalResults);
ctx.close();
```

This also corresponds with the output you posted:

> Total members: 1
>   mak@xxx.coom
>   exception :: java.lang.NullPointerException

The first operation on `ctx` after you closed it triggers the `NullPointerException`. You also close the (same?) `ctx` at the end of your `doFilterSearch`.

Comment: Thanks I got the ctx.close(); at the end of "doFilterSearch" procedure, commenting that is resoved the issue and now I am getting List of Email Addresses by passing a Group Name, Thanks you very much Mr. Halk, it was a great help :)